# How to mock a HttpErrorResponse on HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors, ngxs

I have an HttpMockInterceptor class in order to run my project without manipulating the real data on the database.

I'm returning a HttpResponse with the desired data depending of the endpoint, but when I'm try to send a HttpErrorResponse my HttpService don't event notice of the error.

**This is the interceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpMockRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    const { url } = request;
    for (const petition of urls) {
      if (new RegExp(petition.url).test(url)) {
        const response = petition.response(request);
        const { default: payload, status } = response;
        console.log('Petition intercepted, loading from json:', petition.url);

        if (status === 404) {
          return of(
            new HttpErrorResponse({
              status: 404,
              error: 'Something Happened'
            })
          );
        }
        return of(
          new HttpResponse({
            status: 200,
            body: payload
          })
        );
      }
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

**Http Service**

```
    getUniversityByID(universityID: number) {
    const path = `/university/find/${universityID}`;

    this.sharedHttp.get(path).subscribe(
      (res: Universities) => {

        // Returning HtppResponse works...
        this.store.dispatch(new GetUniversitySuccess(res));
      },
      err => {

        // Returning HtppErrorResponse don't works...
        this.store.dispatch(new GetUniversityError(err.message));
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Because without mock you got an Observable error and not success, don't you have to use `Observable.throw()` ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12857

Comment: @Gilsdav Observable.throw() didn't work but that lead me to use throwError(). I'm not able to set custom error messages but at least the error method is now triggered on my service, Thanks.

Comment: `throwError(new Error('Error message'))`